# Getting around CORS with Jenkins and Nginx Web App on same machine, different ports

Tags: javascript, nginx, jenkins, networking, cors

I have been getting this error while trying to start a Jenkins job with some javascript code on a web app that makes an XMLHttpRequest. Both Jenkins and the web app are on the same machine, different ports.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<JENKINS_URL>' from origin '<WEB_APP_URL:443>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Jenkins is on port 8080 but I have redirected it to port 80. I have the web app on port 443. I have the following lines in the nginx configuration file correlating to Jenkins

```
location / {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
     proxy_read_timeout  90s;

    }
```

But I still get the error. The weird thing is, when I do a curl to the Jenkins URL such as below

```
curl -u <JENKINS_USER>:<TOKEN> -I <JENKINS_JOB_URL>
```

I get this output

```
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 17:12:12 GMT
Location: http://<JENKINS_URL>/queue/item/331/
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
```

And it has the header, but I don't know what else might be wrong. I might be missing something really obvious, as I am pretty new to this and have never dealt with CORS before, but any help is really appreciated, thanks. Happy to upload additional information if needed.

One extra thing, I also edited the following parameter in the /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file as below.

```
JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

I had installed a plugin called "CORS support for Jenkins" the other day without configuring it. I think by default Jenkins was looking at this plugin and saw that I had it disabled.

Once I enabled the plugin and configured it in (JENKINS_URL)/configure, as well as removed the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" line in my nginx configuration, my javascript now works.